# Error: "No devices registered in member center" - Invalid UDID?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-provisioning, udid

I am receiving the errors "No matching provisioning profiles found"[for your UDID], "The selected team doesn't have an iOS Developer Program membership" (Yes, it does.  It's active.),  and "Unable to create provisioning profile because your team has no devices registered in the Member Center. Please connect a device and enable it for development, and add it to the Member Center." (I already have an active provisioning profile in the Member Center.).

When I try to register my Macbook as a development device, I receive the error, "Please enter a valid Hardware UDID".  My path is iOS Developer site->Members Center->"Manage your certificates, App IDs, devices, and provisioning profiles."->Devices->Register Manually.  I copy and pasted my Macbook's Hardware UDID from About This Mac->More Info->System Report-> Hardware UDID.

Do I have to provide Xcode with an Apple iOS device (Not just an Apple device like my Macbook) in order to publish my completed, simulator tested code?  Is there something else I'm supposed to do with this?

Answer (score 8):

This answer is posted a bit further down the line than when the question was posted.  I'm using Xcode 6, but had the same issue.  The deal is that Xcode is looking for a provisioning profile that has an **iOS device** associated with it.  In this case 'development device' means an iOS device - a target device, if you will, and not the machine you are developing on.

### Step 1

To create a Provisioning Profile, you’ll need to log in to your Apple Developer account (http://developer.apple.com, then go to **Member Center** in the nav at the top of the site).  Supposedly you can also do it from the Organizer window in Xcode, but I couldn’t.

Once you log in to your developer account, enter the ‘Certificates, Identifiers & and Profiles’ area and you will see a short article titled **Getting Started with iOS Provisioning Profiles**.  Read it, it’s short and helpful.

Near the bottom of the article is a link to create provisioning files manually.  Click it.  **This will take you to a short wizard for generating provisioning profiles.**

> If you read that little article, you’re aware that there are two kinds
>   of provisioning files - development and distribution.  Or maybe you
>   already knew.  But be sure to know now, because the first step in this
>   process is to select whether to create a profile for development or
>   distribution.  I haven’t set up a profile for distribution, yet, so
>   the rest of this answer will fork towards setting up a profile for
>   development.

### Step 2

You can set up a development profile one of two ways -

1. A *specific* profile for a specific app (and remember, you can create multiple profiles)
2. A *wildcard* profile that you can use in the development of any app

The *wildcard* option works best for my situation, but I expect the remaining steps to be more or less the same, either way.

### Step 3

The next step in the process is to register your device/s.  You have the option of registering just one device for your provisioning profile, or multiple.  Either way, the process is the same - you need to provide a name and a UDID for each device you register to the profile.

**Getting the UDID**

> Getting the UDID may seem tricky if you don’t already know how to get
>   this information, but it's easy.  Plug your device in to your machine,
>   open iTunes, and view your device.  You will see your device’s Serial
>   Number listed.  Click on it, and it will change to your device’s UDID.
>   Incidentally, if you click on the UDID, you’ll get the ECID, and after
>   that the Product Type.
>
> To copy the UDID, go to iTunes main menu Edit -> Copy UDID.  The
>   normal Copy functionality has temporarily changed to ‘Copy UDID’. 
>   Note that you can not select the UDID in your dashboard and copy it
>   that way.

All that’s left is to click the Continue button, and then confirm that the information you’ve entered is correct before hitting the Continue button for the last time.  You can edit your info at this point, but once you hit the Continue button the profile can’t be uncreated.

And that’s it.

Two blog posts that helped me walk through this, complete with extensive instructions and images, are:

Device Provisioning at developer.xamarin.com
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/

Finding Your iPhone’s Unique Identifier (UDID) at www.innerfence.com
https://www.innerfence.com/howto/find-iphone-unique-device-identifier-udid

Comment: What if you don't own an iOS device? Does that mean you can't publish your app?

Comment: Sometimes Apple has a kind of mafia style

Comment: I totally agree with @johnnyfittizio ;)

Answer (score 1):

No need to copy UDID of your Mac! That's insane.

Instead, you need a real iDevice to publish and release iOS apps. You connect your devices and add them to portal in the XCode Organizer:
[image]
When the device was added - it has a green indicator near it. And yes, you can then submit an iOS app provided the device you connected is OK and the build target is indeed the iDevice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register a mobile device with a developer program to publish to the app store (although it's a good idea for testing etc.). To submit, you need to select the target "iOS Device" and go to `Product->Archive` which will give you the option to submit for validation/to App Store.

Comment: This just gives me an error saying I have no provisioning profile, and attempting to create one yields  `Unable to create a provisioning profile because your team has no devices registered in the Member Center. Please connect a device, enable it for development, and add it to the Membership Center using the Organizer.`

Comment: am not having the ipone device .. and having developer licence and build app in xcode.. how can i publish it to appstore.. ie whithout a device UDID

Answer (score 0):

Select "Mac Apps" from the dropdown menu (top left) where it is currently displaying the words "iOS Apps".

Answer (score -1):

You need to enter UDID of devices on which your application will run(iPhone,iPad),not of your mac .

Comment: enter the UDID where ?